# how to make the submenu to appear properly

Tags: css, html, list, menu

I am trying to create a **submenu** for a menubar , and i set the submenu to `absolute positioning` but the display of submenu **not appearing below to the parent menu list**.It appears in a **static position(same place)** for all the menu list's submenu;

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sivashanmugam_kannan/fyv8gjer/5/)

however when i set all the menu lists to be `float : left` , the submenu works but i don't want to set float : left for menu lists.

[jsfiddle-after-setting-float-left](http://jsfiddle.net/sivashanmugam_kannan/fyv8gjer/6/)

how to make the submenu to appear properly without changing float:left for menu list.

Comment: please also (always) include the relevant parts of code here

Comment: You should just take what you need from : http://bootsnipp.com/tags/menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/fyv8gjer/10/

```css
#menu-button{
 display:none;
 text-align: center;
}

.menu-bar{
 float : left;
 width : 100%;
 background-color: #00467f;
}


.menu-bar ul {
 text-align:center;
 background-color: #00467f;
    list-style-type: none;
}


.menu-bar li{
 cursor: pointer;
    display: inline;
    padding-left :1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    position:relative;
}
.menu-bar li a{
 color : white;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.active-menu{
 background-color: #4D9C37;
 padding-top : 0.5%;
 padding-bottom:0.5%;
 border-radius : 4px; 
}

.menu-bar li ol {
    position : absolute;/********if this position is relative the menu collapses*******/
    top:15px;
    left:0px;
    border:1px solid #e7e7e7;
    display:none;
    background:#fff;
}
.menu-bar li ol a {
color : silver;
}
.menu-bar li:hover ol{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="menu-bar">
  <ul>
   <li id="menu-button"><a>MENU</a></li>
   <div id="menu-pages">
    <li class="active-menu"><a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS & SERVICES</a>
                    <ol><!--submenu-->
      <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
        </ol>
                </li>
    <li><a href="#">EVENTS & ACTIVITIES</a>
                    <ol><!--submenu-->    
      <li><a href="#">events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">activities</a></li>
     </ol>
                </li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CAREERS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
   </div>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: could you please tell me why the left : 0px given and what was the default value of left : 0px for the submenu list and why is that required

Comment: We tell the browser where exactly we want the inner (`absolute`) element to be placed in relation to the outer (`relative`) element. This is done using four possible properties: `top, bottom, left`, and `right`.  Using two properties is enough. The inner element, by default, starts out in the top left corner of the outer element.

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative;` to `.menu-bar li`

Demo Link http://jsfiddle.net/fyv8gjer/4/